# Does Virtual Box have an alternative to VMware Server?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-server

I really like being able to log in to my web access of VMWare server and starting my VM when I need too. However, I would really like to be able to do this with Virtualbox. There are many reasons why, however the biggest problem is that you cannot install the web plugin on Mac OS x.

Oh and I love virtualbox :)
Let me know Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no web interface that comes with VirtualBox unfortunately. There is however an open source project which aims to implement one called [vboxweb](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/), which is still in the development stages:

[image]

Comment: Great Find!!!  I will definitely give it a try!